# Listing all the certificates stored in the user's computer from an ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography, certificate

I don't really think this is a doable thing, but I need to find a way. Our ASP.NET website allows users to view/download invoices either as reports or as an XML document.

Now, the problem is, these XML invoices should be signed using XAdes (which derives from XMLDsig). In order to do so, a certificate is needed. Certificates won't be stored in the server machine, but individually into each user´s machine. So, when a user clicks on the download button, they should be asked which of their certificates they would like to use to sign the XML invoice.

Is it possible to read the user local store remotelly in a ASP.NET Page? I don't mean getting the certificates inside the server local store, under the Current User.

As far as I know, this is something that needs to be done using an ActiveX control.

Comment: You could also look into using [Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404700(v=vs.95).aspx), or having server side code access the client directly (not via HTTP) and examine the certs. That's of course assuming the machines are on the same network and the website has the necessary permissions.

Answer (score 0):

An ASP.NET application cannot read directly from a client's certificate store, but it can request that the client present a suitable certificate. The behavior varies slightly depending on the browser, but generally speaking if more than one matching client certificate is found the browser will pop a dialog asking the user the select the certificate they want to authenticate with.

In most cases, you would configure the application to find the client certificate using an attribute like issuer name, which could be used by multiple certificates:

```
<clientCertificate x509FindType="FindByIssuerName" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" findValue="MY-ISSUING-CA" />
```

I'm not sure exactly how granular you need to be with the above configuration so you may need to mess around with it a bit, but it should help to get you going in the right direction.